# Merge green screen image with a background image using Python

Tags: python, merge, python-imaging-library

Hey guys I've  been trying to merge 2 images(one is a green screen image with a object in the middle of the photo, the second one is a of a forest) using PIL. Both images are the same size(800, 600) I've tried to merge them into a new image but its seeming impossible at my end.

Any code solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would break the problem down into pieces: first you're going to want to remove the green screen background from your first image. You can do this with `PIL` by iterating through every frame of the video and removing the green color. There are [great guides](http://salgat.blogspot.com/2015/04/using-pythons-pil-library-to-remove.html) to do so online.

Next, you're going to want to put the first image on top of the second. You can achieve that using the `paste()` method, also detailed in [online guides](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-paste/).

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in Python, but our instructor gave another way to get this done by using if conditions and nested for loops

```
*from PIL import Image
penguin_image = Image.open ("penguin.jpg")
beach_image = Image.open("beach.jpg")

penguin_width, penguin_height = penguin_image.size

#Accessing the pixels of the images
penguin_pixel = penguin_image.load()
beach_pixel = beach_image.load()

#Image inspection
(r0,g0,b0) = penguin_pixel[0,0]
(r1,g1,b1) = penguin_pixel[1,0]
(r2,g2,b2) = penguin_pixel[2,0]
(r3,g3,b3) = penguin_pixel[3,0]
(r4,g4,b4) = penguin_pixel[4,0]
(r5,g5,b5) = penguin_pixel[5,0]
(br,bg,bb) = beach_pixel[0,0]

print(penguin_width, penguin_height)
print(br, bg, bb)

#Creation of new image to hold combined pixels
combined_image = Image.new("RGB", penguin_image.size)
combined_pixel = combined_image.load()

#Checking for green
for ver in range (0, penguin_height):
    for hor in range(0, penguin_width):
        (r,g,b) = penguin_pixel[hor, ver]
        (br,bg,bb) = beach_pixel[hor, ver]
        if (r < 100 and g == 207 and b < 100):
            combined_pixel[hor,ver] = (br, bg, bb)
        else:
            combined_pixel[hor,ver] = (r, g, b)*
```

combined_image.show()